# sql case when newValue else previousValue

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update, case

I'm trying to create a Update from Select where in a specific case (88)  the previous value should be used to update the column field

```
UPDATE myTable
SET MyDateCol = CASE MYSelect.Indicator 
                WHEN 88 THEN @previosValue 
                ELSE MYSelect.NewValue
FROM  myTable
INNER JOIN    (    ...    ) AS MYSelect

ON myTable.ID = MYSelect.ID
```

EXAMPLE:

```
MYSelect             | myTable
                     |
Indicator NewValue   | MyDateCol 
   0         1       |    1
   1         2       |    2
   88        3       |    2 <-
   3         4       |    4
   4         5       |    5
   5         6       |    6
   6         7       |    7
   88        8       |    7 <-
```

Full Update

```
UPDATE [dbo].[BestellDetails]
   SET [Datum] = CASE MYTABLE.WochenTag WHEN 88  THEN lag(MyDate) over(order by MYTABLE.MyDate)  ELSE MyDate END
FROM  [BestellDetails]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT INNERTabelle.BestellDetailId,INNERTabelle.WochenTag, DATEADD (dd,INNERTabelle.WochenTag, INNERTabelle.NewDatum) AS MyDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT BestellDetailId, 
                    dbo.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(dbo.Bestellung.Jahr, 
                    dbo.Bestellung.Kalenderwoche) AS NewDatum,
                    (CASE BestellDetails.RefMenuId WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefMoId THEN 0 
                                                   WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefDiId THEN 1 
                                                   WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefMiId THEN 2 
                                                   WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefDoId THEN 3 
                                                   WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefFrId THEN 4 
                                                   WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefSaId THEN 5 
                                                   WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefSoId THEN 6 ELSE 88 END) AS WochenTag
        FROM            dbo.Speiseplandetails 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.BestellDetails ON dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefMoId 
        OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefDiId 
        OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefMiId 
        OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefDoId 
        OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefFrId 
        OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefSaId 
        OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefSoId 

        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Bestellung ON dbo.BestellDetails.RefBestellId = dbo.Bestellung.BestellId

        order by BestellDetailId

    ) as INNERTabelle
) AS MYTABLE

ON [BestellDetails].BestellDetailId = MYTABLE.BestellDetailId
```

Comment: If it were sql server or oracle, you can look at the `lag()` function.

Comment: Define "previous". Is it based on ordering the values in the `NewValue` column?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, indeed

Comment: Can we have two rows in succession that both have an `88` indicator?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever why should we need 2 indicator rows is one not enough? and sure you can create 1 more row if you need

Comment: My concern was - say that the row with `NewValue` 4 *also* had `Indicator` set to 88. In that case, you would presumably want `MyDateCol` to be 2 (rather than 3, which was the value of the `NewValue` column in the previous row, but that value wasn't used). That adds significant complication and means that the `LAG` based approaches in some answers won't work. So, we need to know if that's a possible situation we need to deal with.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right, currently i test your  update query it will take some more minutes to finish then i can tell you if it works like we expected thanks for your time :)

Comment: @DhruvJoshi i will, when the query is finish so that i can check the outcome (current execution time 14min :D  and still increasing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below query. 
It has optimized your query and also takes care of cases where there are repeated `88` values. In my case I've used `NULL` instead of `88`.

> Can we have two rows in succession that both have an 88 indicator? – 
>   Damien_The_Unbeliever

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
BestellDetailId int, row_num int,MyDate date
)

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
    BestellDetailId,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by BestellDetailId) as row_num,        
    (
    CASE BestellDetails.RefMenuId 
                               WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefMoId THEN DATEADD (dd,0, dbo.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(dbo.Bestellung.Jahr, dbo.Bestellung.Kalenderwoche) )
                               WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefDiId THEN DATEADD (dd,1, dbo.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(dbo.Bestellung.Jahr, dbo.Bestellung.Kalenderwoche) )
                               WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefMiId THEN DATEADD (dd,2, dbo.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(dbo.Bestellung.Jahr, dbo.Bestellung.Kalenderwoche) )
                               WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefDoId THEN DATEADD (dd,3, dbo.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(dbo.Bestellung.Jahr, dbo.Bestellung.Kalenderwoche) )
                               WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefFrId THEN DATEADD (dd,4, dbo.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(dbo.Bestellung.Jahr, dbo.Bestellung.Kalenderwoche) )
                               WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefSaId THEN DATEADD (dd,5, dbo.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(dbo.Bestellung.Jahr, dbo.Bestellung.Kalenderwoche) )
                               WHEN Speiseplandetails.RefSoId THEN DATEADD (dd,6, dbo.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(dbo.Bestellung.Jahr, dbo.Bestellung.Kalenderwoche) )
                               ELSE NULL END
    ) AS MyDate

FROM  dbo.Speiseplandetails 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.BestellDetails ON dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefMoId 
                OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefDiId 
                OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefMiId 
                OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefDoId 
                OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefFrId 
                OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefSaId 
                OR dbo.BestellDetails.RefMenuId = dbo.Speiseplandetails.RefSoId 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Bestellung ON dbo.BestellDetails.RefBestellId = dbo.Bestellung.BestellId
order by BestellDetailId

--updating the temp table with correct values
update t1
set t1.myDate=t3.myDate
from #temp t1 left join #temp t3 
on t3.row_num in 
(select max(row_num) from #temp t2 where t2.myDate is not null and t2.row_num<t1.row_num)
where t1.MyDate is NULL

UPDATE [dbo].[BestellDetails]
   SET [Datum] = MYTABLE.myDate
FROM  [BestellDetails]

INNER JOIN
#temp AS MYTABLE
ON [BestellDetails].BestellDetailId = MYTABLE.BestellDetailId
```

below is the sample fiddle for updating a table with last value
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c78ae/8

Comment: Execution time 1:15:57 on my local DB :D, but it does what i want and it will run just one time

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET MyDateCol = CASE MYSelect.Indicator 
                WHEN 88 THEN (select lag(newvalue) over(order by newvalue) from MySelect) -- @previosValue 
                ELSE MYSelect.NewValue
FROM  myTable
INNER JOIN    (    ...    ) AS MYSelect
ON myTable.ID = MYSelect.ID
```

This is assuming the previous value has to be selected based on the ascending order in `newvalue` column.

Comment: `Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.` it may hat todo with my `DATEADD`

Comment: I tried your modification, now it is unable to find `MySelect` in the `Select ... over ... ` part

Answer (score 1):

`lag()` should do what you want.  You can put it directly in the `MySelect` definition.  Or use a subquery:

```
WITH myselect as (
      . . .
     )
UPDATE myTable
    SET MyDateCol = (CASE MYSelect.Indicator 
                        WHEN 88 THEN MYSelecct.prevvalue 
                        ELSE MYSelect.NewValue
                     END
FROM  myTable INNER JOIN
      (SELECT myselect.*, lag(newvalue) over (order by newvalue) as prevvalue
       FROM myselect
      ) myselect
      ON myTable.ID = MYSelect.ID;
```